# How to print a constant which changes in childs and parents classes?

Tags: php, constants

I have a parent class which have a constant ID defined, but I have X childs with the same constant ID name defined, with different value.

How can I show the value of the constant in the method of the parent without having to overwrite the code on each child?

Idk if I'm expressing right, so I show you an example of what I mean.

That's a short example of my parent class (there is missing uses, namespace, etc.. but you'll get what I mean):

```
class RootLenSkiStatus extends AbstractSkiStatus
{

    const ID_SKI = 20;

    protected function getSnowType()
    {
        $snowtype = 'X';
        switch ($snowType) {
            case 'X':
                $snowType = SnowType::SNOW_TYPE_X;
                break;
            default:
                throw new \Exception('Method getSnowType from ID_SKI ' . static::ID_SKI . ' returns new Snowtype, not defined: ' . $snowType);
                break;
        }
        $this->dto->setSnowType($snowType);
    }
}
```

And there's a short example of one of my child classes:

```
class RootmadnessSkiStatus extends RootLenSkiStatus
{

    const ID_SKI = 40;

}
```

If I enter to 'local.blablabla/check-id/40', calling the const with an 'static::ID_SKI', It'll return me 40, and if I change 40 for 20, It'll return me 40 too.

But, if I enter 'local.blablabla/check-id/40', calling the const with an 'self::ID_SKI', It'll return me 20, and if I change 40 for 20, It'll return me 20, obviously.

I have more than 1 child, and It only returns one static value from one child, It doesn't changes.

I think you'll understand what I mean now.. can you help me?

Thanks ;).

Update:

My bad, the PHP Version I'm using is 5.5.9.

Comment: This question is missing the used version of PHP, and it is important here.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Added, my bad,  ty for remember it to me ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP>=5.0

```
<?php 
class A {
    const FIRST = 20;
    static function getSelf(){
        echo self::FIRST;
    }
    static function getStatic(){
        echo static::FIRST;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    const FIRST = 40;
    static function getParent(){
        echo parent::FIRST;
    }
}

echo A::FIRST;//20
echo A::getSelf();//20
echo A::getStatic();//20
echo B::FIRST;//40 - so use classname out of child if you want the child value
echo B::getSelf();//20
echo B::getStatic();//40 - so use static in child if you want the child value
echo B::getParent();//20
```

Comment: @LastFit Updated to PHP Version before 5.6

Comment: The problem is, that I can't call the child classes by their name, It have to be dinamically, and something like: $name = 'B', to do an if, and then something like $name::getSelf, returns an error.

Comment: Note: getSelf and getStatic where example methods to show what you get if you call stuff from given places.

Comment: I get it, but I can't call directly to the Class name, cuz It's dinamically called by the ID, I can't choose the Class to return.

Comment: A Option is `print forward_static_call(array('B', 'getSelf'));` or `call_user_func()` but rething your logic here: calling static fields from not initialized classes with variables.